# Upload IPA to Testflight AppStoreConnect

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, app-store-connect, ipa, bitrise

Using `xcrun altool --upload-app --file filePath --type ios --username username --password password` no longer seems to work, getting the following errors:

```
*** Error: ERROR: [ContentDelivery.Uploader] createRequestBuildCreateJsonWithResponse: caught an exception: -[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb10a69f91362ac79
*** Error: Exception caught. -[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb10a69f91362ac79 (-1010)
 {
    NSLocalizedDescription = "Exception caught.";
    NSLocalizedFailureReason = "-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb10a69f91362ac79";
}
```

Does anyone know if there has been recent changes to this?